# Are there any examples of certain website (or mobile app) UX analysis?

Tags: guidelines

Having business requirements from stakeholders, I want to present UX analysis for a website.

The problem is that I haven`t seen guidelines and structure how to do this.

Any way, example in PDF, PPT, or DOC format could help to solve this issue.

Comment: Probably HIG by Apple for iOS apps — http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Offtopic to the question - IMHO it would really help if you spelled your username in latin characters, that way people can reply to you without having to copy-paste the username.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use the analysis mentioned in the article [How To Quantify The User Experience](http://www.sitepoint.com/quantify-user-experience/). It is a high level subjective scale where you get score (5-100) in four different areas:

[image]

Use five different statements in each area and make (subjective) measurement giving them each a value of 1-20. Then you'll get a (again subjective) value in four different areas that you can plot on a graph, if needed. The table may look like this:

[image]

If that does not meet your goal, you could always use the [System Usability Scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_usability_scale), which is more scientific and well described in the article [Measuring Usability With The System Usability Scale (SUS)](http://www.measuringusability.com/sus.php).

Answer (score 0):

Are you presenting the results of a heuristic analysis, or the results of testing? The templates at http://usability.gov/templates/index.html are a good starting point.